# pagination with ng-table in angular

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am using [ng-table](http://ng-table.com) plugin to paginate a table like this:

```
$scope.ngtableParams = new ngTableParams({}, {
                counts:false,
                getData: function(params) {
                    return $http.get($rootScope.app.authApi + 'questions/' + selectedSubtopic.id).then(function(data) {
                        params.total(data.data.length);
                        return data.data;
                    });
                }
            });
```

Funnily ng-table calls getData() function everytime a user clicks on page numbers. And hits the entire thing again and fetches all the records and displays them. So pagination is essentially useless.

I need to have a client side pagination. Is it possible with ng-table?

**Tried this as well**

```
$http.get($rootScope.app.authApi + 'questions/' + selectedSubtopic.id)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.ngtableParams = new ngTableParams({count:5}, {
                        counts:[],
                        paginationMaxBlocks: 13,
                        paginationMinBlocks: 2,
                        total:data.length,
                        getData: function(params) {
                            return data;
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Same result with the above as well!

Comment: can you try separating the backed call. You can do the backend call outside the `ng-table` decleration, fetch the data and store somewhere and in `getData()` you can return the stored data.

Comment: your particular about ng-table??

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of ng-table I end up using the following:

```
function IssueCtrl(NgTableParams, IssueService) {
    var self = this;

    loadTable();

    function loadTable() {
        IssueService.getIssues().then(function (issues) {
            self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 5
            }, {
                dataset: issues // might be data instead of dataset depending on ng-table version
            });
        });
    }
 }
```

Client side pagination is properly working thanks to `dataset`.

So it should be something like this for OP:

```
$http.get($rootScope.app.authApi + 'questions/' + selectedSubtopic.id)
            .success(function(result){
                $scope.ngtableParams = new ngTableParams({count:5}, {
                    counts:[],
                    paginationMaxBlocks: 13,
                    paginationMinBlocks: 2,
                    total:result.length,
                    dataset: result // might be data instead of dataset depending on ng-table version
                });
            });
```